# How to sort list of data in a sheet based on custom algorithm?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have attached some code which attempts to do this, but I am having difficulty returning the array to the sheet. The data is formatted as below.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H6jF.png
With the other columns, it is simple to just call SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().sort(#);
However, With this, essentially I want to maintain the order of the list, except any value with "Seen" in the fourth column is put to the end. I attempted this with:

```
function sortProgress() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var output = [];
  var i = 0;
  while (sheet[i] != null) {
    if (sheet[i][4] != "Seen") {
      output.push(sheet[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  i = 0;
  while (sheet[i] != null) {
    if (sheet[i][4] == "Seen") {
      output.push(sheet[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  sheet.getRange("A1:A20").setValues(output);
}
```

But I didn't know how to actually display this to the google spreadsheet. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably follow Raserhin's answer as it is just more consistent with the logic, however, this is what I ended up implementing, for completeness.

```
function sortProgress() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("D2:D1000").offset(0,0,sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()-1);
                                           range.setValues(range.getValues().map(function(row){
    return row.map(function(cell){
      return cell === cell ? cell+'a' : cell;
    });
  }));
  var sortRange = sheet.getRange("A2:F1000");
  sortRange.sort(4);
  range = sheet.getRange("D2:D1000").offset(0,0,sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()-1);
                                           range.setValues(range.getValues().map(function(row){
    return row.map(function(cell){
      return cell === cell ? cell.substring(0,cell.length-1) : cell;
    });
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort the array providing a `compareFunction`. In this case you will only need to check the `Seen` or not column.

```
const data = [["M", "Seen", "Movie"],["M", "1/3", "Movie"],["M", "Seen", "Movie"],["M", "", "TV"]];
data.sort((a, b) =>{
  if(a[1] != "Seen" && b[1] == "Seen"){
    // a comes first
    return -1
  }
  if(a[1] == "Seen" && b[1] != "Seen"){
    // b comes first
    return 1
  }
   // mantain current order
  return 0
  
});
console.log(data);
```

This gives the correct output:

> `\>\>\> Array [Array ["M", "1/3", "Movie"], Array ["M", "", "TV"], Array ["M", "Seen", "Movie"], Array ["M", "Seen", "Movie"]]`

After having this array sorted you just can do the [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) as you did in your code snippet.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, I did a slightly different method of adding 0 to each empty cell, sorting the sheet, then removing a trailing 0 from each cell. It works, so I'm not touching it haha

Comment: That's fair, If ain't broken.... But please consider posting your solution as an answer so other people may benefit from it.